# AutocompleteTextView uneditable after selection

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

This might sound dumb but I really need help!

I am able to do all the tasks related to autoCompleteTextView, but I want to disable the editing after selection of Item, i.e. he shouldn't be able to add character after selecting Item from AutoCompleteTextview list but he should be able to delete the string.

I tried finding any link related to this, any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a item click listener for the autocompletetextview.

```
autoComplete.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And when you click on something just disable it.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3){
       autoComplete.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Maybe you should think more about this, what if the user want to change it's mind and change the selection?